# My file doesn't seem to be reading in data as an array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, ifstream

So for some reason my program and input file read function doesn't seem to be reading in any of the data from my input file. And nothing is flagged in Visual Studio 2013.
Here is my input file read function:

```
void readem(listType p[], int &numlist)
{
    int i = 0, id = 0;
    string first, last;
    ifstream fin("extracredit.dat");
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        getline(fin, p[i].last, ',');
        fin >> p[i].first >> p[i].id >> ws;
        i++;
        insertlist(p, first, last, id);
    }
    numlist = i;
}
```

Anyone have any ideas why this doesn't seem to be working? Thanks!!

Comment: (following discussion in my previous answer) The general output of the program does not help much, as we do not have the whole code (which is probably too long anyway). But could you add something like std::cout << p[i].first << "; " << p[i].last << std::endl; after your "i++", and give us the output of this particular line ?

Comment: Just tried cout << p[i].id << p[i].first << p[i].last << endl; and all it's outputting is : -858993460 a bunch of times when I run it. Not sure if that helps or not.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing uninitialized "first" and "last " strings when calling insertlist. Did you mean :

```
insertlist(p, p[i].first, p[i].last, id)
```

?

I am not sure what your code actually does, but this is probably the cause of your problem.

Comment: I have    string first, last;    inside the function and it worked that way while reading the file in with pointers. We are supposed to read it in for this program as an array. And that insertlist is another function, my issue is it isn't reading any info in at all.

Comment: Could you print the contents of p[i].first and p[i].last before the call to insertlist, and edit your question to say what it gives you ? It would be easier to understand if we know the code, the actual output and the output you expected.

Comment: This function is only to read in the info from the input file. I print it in another function, but for some reason it isn't even reading in any info to print. The actual output from the previous program using pointers and links looks like:

    Students in CSCI 112 Fall 2014 
    ================================
    ID    First         Last           
    ================================
    112   Jared         Boese          
    164   Kylie         Garcia         
    199   Rory          Mollenkamp     
    202   Han           Solo           
    291   Alex          Martinez

Comment: Mine prints out with just the title parts and none of the info (IDs, First names, Last names)